# Why I need to overload the method when use it as ThreadStart() parameter?

Tags: c#

I want to save file using the separate thread. Don't have experience with threads using.

```
private ObservableCollection<PersonEntitiy> allStaff;
private Thread dataFileTransactionsThread;

#region Constructor
public staffRepository() {
    allStaff = getStaffDataFromTextFile();
    dataFileTransactionsThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(UpdateDataFile));
}
#endregion

public void UpdateDataFile(ObservableCollection<PersonEntitiy> allStaff) {

    dataFileTransactionsThread.Start();
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("dataFileTransactions Thread Status："+ dataFileTransactionsThread.ThreadState);

    string containsWillBeSaved = "";

    // ...

    File.WriteAllText(fullPathToDataFile, containsWillBeSaved);
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Data Save Successfull");

    // depricated but did not deside what is better to use instead yet
    dataFileTransactionsThread.Suspend(); 
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("dataFileTransactions Thread Status：" + dataFileTransactionsThread.ThreadState);

}
```

IDE displays that `UpdateDataFile()` has not been overloaded. If to add the below code, application will be compiled, but I need to understand the role of `UpdateDataFile()` - method overloading without parameters.

```
// Overload is required but I don't understand why
public void UpdateDataFile() {

}
```

Comment: [Because `ThreadStart` is a parameterless delegate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadstart(v=vs.110).aspx). You have to give it a method that the compiler will accept. If you want a threadstart method with a parameter, [use `ParameterizedThreadStart` instead](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1h2f2459(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Why have you made `allStaff` a field and then pass it as a parameter?

Comment: @Ed Plunkett, Thank you for the answer. I need to understand the following chain: suppost we call the `UpdateDataFile(ObservableCollection<PersonEntitiy> allStaff)` from the other class, than this method starts the `dataFileTransactionsThread`. What the next?

Comment: Then the code in `UpdateDataFile` will execute.on the other thread.

Comment: @Enigmativity, In `UpdateDataFile(ObservableCollection<PersonEntitiy> allStaff)`, the `ObservableCollection` comes from the other class, than it will be stringified and saved to file. But the current class also uses `ObservableCollection<PersonEntitiy> allStaff` (e. g. when reads the file and creates the `ObservableCollection` from the data).

Comment: @Ed Plunkett, O'K and what will be with `public void UpdateDataFile()` empty-body method?

Comment: @GurebuBokofu I just told you: The code in it executes. If there is no code, nothing happens. That is the method that the thread executes. The one you give it, only the one you give it, and no other method that might have the same name. Are you saying you want to pass it a reference to a method, and you want it to find out somehow what the method's name is, and go out looking for other methods with the same name and call them instead? Where should it look? What if two other overloads have the same name? Which should it call? That would be crazy. It just executes what you give it.

Comment: @Ed Plunkett , OK, got it. Thanks for the explanations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to overload it because `ThreadStart`'s constructor takes the parameterless void function and you're trying to use a function which takes parameters. You also appear to be starting the thread from within it's called method, this shouldn't happen. Might I suggest you try the following:

```
private ObservableCollection<PersonEntitiy> allStaff;
private Thread dataFileTransactionsThread;

#region Constructor
public staffRepository() {
    allStaff = getStaffDataFromTextFile();
    dataFileTransactionsThread = new Thread(UpdateDataFileThread);
}
#endregion

public void UpdateDataFile(ObservableCollection<PersonEntitiy> allStaff)     
{
    dataFileTransactionsThread.Start(allStaff);

    // If you want to wait until the save finishes, uncomment the following line
    // dataFileTransactionsThread.Join();
}

private void UpdateDataFileThread(object data) {
    var allStaff = (ObservableCollection<PersonEntitiy>)data;

    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("dataFileTransactions Thread Status："+ dataFileTransactionsThread.ThreadState);

    string containsWillBeSaved = "";

    // ...

    File.WriteAllText(fullPathToDataFile, containsWillBeSaved);

    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Data Save Successfull");

    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("dataFileTransactions Thread Status：" + dataFileTransactionsThread.ThreadState);

}
```

Please note that you will only be able to call `UpdateDataFile` once before you must re-construct the `dataFileTransactionsThread` object, if you want to avoid this and are hell bent on using threads you could construct the thread object inside the public `UpdateDataFile`

Comment: In the last line( `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("dataFileTransactions Thread Status：" + dataFileTransactionsThread.ThreadState);`), the thread is running yet. Do I need to stop It here?

Comment: The thread will exit as soon as the method has finished executing (in this case after that line), at this point the ``dataFileTransactionsThread`` object becomes unusable and must be reconstructed.