# Restart the thread when it will stop

Tags: c#, multithreading

In the question [Why I need to overload the method when use it as ThreadStart() parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46677638/why-i-need-to-overload-the-method-when-use-it-as-threadstart-parameter/46678078?noredirect=1#comment80304721_46678078), I got the following solution for saving file in separate thread problem (it's required to save file when delete or add new instance of the `PersonEntity`):

```
private ObservableCollection<PersonEntitiy> allStaff;
private Thread dataFileTransactionsThread;

public staffRepository() {
    allStaff = getStaffDataFromTextFile();
    dataFileTransactionsThread = new Thread(UpdateDataFileThread);
}

public void UpdateDataFile(ObservableCollection<PersonEntitiy> allStaff)     
{
    dataFileTransactionsThread.Start(allStaff);

    // If you want to wait until the save finishes, uncomment the following line
    // dataFileTransactionsThread.Join();
}

private void UpdateDataFileThread(object data) {
    var allStaff = (ObservableCollection<PersonEntitiy>)data;

    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("dataFileTransactions Thread Status："+ dataFileTransactionsThread.ThreadState);

    string containsWillBeSaved = "";

    // ...

    File.WriteAllText(fullPathToDataFile, containsWillBeSaved);

    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Data Save Successfull");

    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("dataFileTransactions Thread Status：" + dataFileTransactionsThread.ThreadState);

}
```

Now, if sequentially delete two instances of the `PersonEntity`, `System.Threading.ThreadStateException: Thread is still executing or don't finished yet. Restart is impossible.` will occur.`.

I understand this exception meaning as a whole, however, the following solution will not be enough: next time, the file will not be saved.

```
if (!dataFileTransactionsThread.IsAlive) {
    dataFileTransactionsThread.Start(allStaff);
}
```

Probably, it't better to restart the thread when it finished, and then save the file again. However, it's also required to provide the code for the case when will be deleted sequentially three or more instances. Just on the conception level, it's simple: we need only newest `allStaff` collection, so the previous unsaved `allStaff` collections or not necessary anymore.

How can I realize above concept on `C#`?

Comment: What does "will be deleted sequentially three or more instances" mean?

Comment: Once the `UpdateDataFileThread` has finished your thread will end. You have to start a new one each time.

Comment: @Enigmativity, "will be deleted" - in means that user will delete three or more list items (which is PersonEntity instances from the collection) by "Delete" button; "sequentially" - not at the same time. Sorry for my English.

Comment: @Enigmativity, thus I need to remove `dataFileTransactionsThread = new Thread(UpdateDataFileThread);` from the constructor?

Comment: You really need to avoid threads like this in the first place. I'll have an answer for you later that shows you how.

Comment: @Enigmativity, O'K, thank you for the ready to do some explanations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to suggest using Microsoft's Reactive Framework. NuGet "System.Reactive".

Then you can do this:

```
IObservable<List<PersonEntity>> query =
    Observable
        .FromEventPattern<NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs>(
            h => allStaff.CollectionChanged += h, h => allStaff.CollectionChanged -= h)
        .Throttle(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2.0))
        .Select(x => allStaff.ToList())
        .ObserveOn(Scheduler.Default);

IDisposable subscription =
    query
        .Subscribe(u =>
        {
            string containsWillBeSaved = "";
            // ...
            File.WriteAllText(fullPathToDataFile, containsWillBeSaved);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Data Save Successful");
        });
```

This code will watch your `allStaff` collection for all changes and then, for every change, it will wait 2 seconds to see if any other changes come thru and if they don't it then takes a copy of your collection (this is crucial for threading to work) and it saves your collection.

It will save no more than once every 2 seconds and it will only save when there has been one or more changes.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I'll try it!